# How to pass html table cell value to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-table

I have no experience with javascripting and need a solution for my html page with a table generated automatically by a shell script. Script outputs the HTML code below.

```
cat plstable.html
<html><head></head><body><table>
<tr><td>1</td><td> The Fratellis - Chelsea Dagger </td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td> Connect Northants: Eternal / Bebe Winans - I Wanna Be The Only One</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td> Virgin_UK_128</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

I need a javascript with onclick when the user clicks the first entry in the table row (e.g. 1, 2 or 3), javascript gets the value from the page named plstable.html, set a variable value (like var x = 1) and run a command in the shell like "mpc play + x" to play the first entry. Javascript should be a seperate file because the shellscript generating the html table becomes complex in the case of adding java code to shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

1. Adds a click (event) listener to every first `<td>` of every `<tr>`
2. On click the **text** is parsed to int (base10), and the number is passed to the handler function (`getNumber(val)`)
3. The handler function prints the value read from the `<td>` to the console

```js
// "grabbing" each row
const rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')

// iterating over each row
for (let i = 0, length = rows.length; i < length; i++) {

  // grabbing the first child element in each row (so no text
  // or other type of nodes - only elements)
  // then adding a click event listener with a callback function
  rows[i].firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    // calling the "designed" function in the event listener
    // callback
    getNumber(parseInt(this.textContent, 10))
  })
}

// the handling function
function getNumber(val) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

```css
td:first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td> The Fratellis - Chelsea Dagger </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> Connect Northants: Eternal / Bebe Winans - I Wanna Be The Only One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td> Virgin_UK_128</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ES6

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("table tr td:first-child")]
  .forEach((td) => td.addEventListener("click",getNumber))

function getNumber() {
  console.log(+this.textContent)
}
```

```css
td:first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td> The Fratellis - Chelsea Dagger </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> Connect Northants: Eternal / Bebe Winans - I Wanna Be The Only One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td> Virgin_UK_128</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```